# mutate() a list based upon another list

Tags: r, mapply

In this example, I have two lists

```
tiers <- list("tier 1", "tier 2", "tier 3")

main <- list(data.frame(a = c("this", "that")), 
             data.frame(a = c("the other", "that too")), 
             data.frame(a = c("once more", "kilgore trout")))
```

and I'd like to `mutate()` each list element (i.e., `data.frame()`) in `main` by adding the value in `tiers` from the corresponding element. I thought `mapply()` would do it:

```
library(dplyr)

mapply(function(x, y) y %>% mutate(tier = x), tiers, main)
```

but I get an unexpected result

```
> mapply(function(x, y) y %>% mutate(tier = x), tiers, main)
     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       
a    factor,2    factor,2    factor,2   
tier Character,2 Character,2 Character
```

while what I expected was

```
[[1]]
     a   tier
1 this tier 1
2 that tier 1

[[2]]
          a   tier
1 the other tier 2
2  that too tier 2

[[3]]
              a   tier
1     once more tier 3
2 kilgore trout tier 3
```

Am I using `mapply()` correctly? If not, is there something I should be using to get the result I'm expecting? I should note that actual data may have up to `n` list elements; I can't hard-code any values in terms of `1:n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you needed was to add `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` in your `mapply` call

```
library(dplyr)
mapply(function(x, y) y %>% mutate(tier = x), tiers, main, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)


#     a   tier
#1 this tier 1
#2 that tier 1

#[[2]]
#          a   tier
#1 the other tier 2
#2  that too tier 2

#[[3]]
#              a   tier
#1     once more tier 3
#2 kilgore trout tier 3
```

`?mapply` says

> SIMPLIFY - attempt to reduce the result to a vector, matrix or higher dimensional array;

`SIMPLIFY` argument is by default `TRUE` in `mapply` and `FALSE` in `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) y %>% mutate(tier = x), tiers, main)
```

---

If you want to keep everything in base R, you could use `cbind`

```
Map(cbind, main, tiers)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, consider `within` or `transform` with `Map` (list version wrapper to `mapply`) and avoid loading a package for one function, `mutate`:

```
Map(function(x, y) within(y, tier <- x), tiers, main)

Map(function(x, y) transform(y, tier = x), tiers, main)
```

Answer (score 2):

In base `R` you could use `Map` with the function `data.frame` if you name the `tier` argument :

```
Map(data.frame, main, tier=tiers)
# [[1]]
#      a   tier
# 1 this tier 1
# 2 that tier 1
# 
# [[2]]
#           a   tier
# 1 the other tier 2
# 2  that too tier 2
# 
# [[3]]
#               a   tier
# 1     once more tier 3
# 2 kilgore trout tier 3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `tidyverse` with `map2`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(main, tiers, ~ .x %>%
           mutate(tiers = .y))
#[[1]]
#     a  tiers
#1 this tier 1
#2 that tier 1

#[[2]]
#          a  tiers
#1 the other tier 2
#2  that too tier 2

#[[3]]
#              a  tiers
#1     once more tier 3
#2 kilgore trout tier 3
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to explore more of the `tidyverse`. I get stuck on the functions that I know and love and I know there's a lot more "new" stuff that's out there.